# on user install app in facebook register him to drupal

Tags: facebook, drupal, authentication, drupal-6

is there a way to create a user to drupal for a user that just now installed my app and make it safe password for him (unique) so i can re-login him using some algorithm that decrypt his password?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that, but requiring passwords to be unique is a bad, very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's a module for that: http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect